# Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I get the error Login failed for user ''. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456) from Azure SQL server when a user tries to login using Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA.

My Azure AD login is within a group, other members of the group can login to the database, but I get the error  `'<token-identified principal>'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)`, however If the user is added to the database, then I can login and it works.

```
create user [myUserName@contoso.com] from external provider
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'myUserName@contoso.com'
```

I was wondering if there is a reason for this.

Comment: Hey, did the suggestion work? do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot. [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 19):

I had this error as well, my workaround was to go into 'Options -> Connection Properties -> manually put the database name I wanted to connect to'

In my org I had only been given permission to the specific database, not the database server.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. If a database is not specified SSMS will try to connect to 'master. Azure SQL DBs are self-contained, hence the user has no permission to connect to 'master'. You may expand your answer with this info.

Comment: This is the correct answer, if you don't set up the DB name in the settings it won't connect to the DB you have access to.

Comment: In my case, I was using the incorrect MS account (between my work & client guest accounts)...

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is an identical issue its already been raised over [**Microsoft Q&A**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/133709/login-failed-for-user-39lttoken-identified-princip.html) Plateform a year ago.

You need to add the users to your SQL DB as AAD Users first to accces the Specifiv SQLServer.

> The error "`Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456 <token-identified-principal>`" means that the user used to login to
> SQL Server Management Studio is invalid. It is usually related to an
> AAD user which is not added on SQL DB that you are trying to connect
> (User DB or Master DB) or that the AAD user is not the AAD Server
> Admin.
>
> You just need to add an AAD user in Azure SQL DB. You can follow the
> steps mentioned here:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities

Note :  Use User UPN(`name@domain.com`) to access the SQL DB not logged on as this user: "`domain\name.surname`" on my environment.

Comment: Hello. Please review y question again, the user is part of a group, the group has access to the database as it was created on the database. There was a particular user who is part of the group, the user got the error message whilst trying to login, however when I created the user account on the DB separate using using the UPN, then it works. Another user who is part of the same group can access the dB without having to create a UPN user on the db.

Comment: Please check is there any privilledge difference between the both the user is who is part of group for one you will able to access and another one is not .

Comment: if this  issue still persists plese reach out to support team.

Comment: I have this same issue. On SSMS 18.06 my Azure account can be part of an AD group and I could sign in to a DB using Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA. Now using Azure Data Studio this is no longer possible. Crazy.

Answer (score 2):

God save the world from Microsoft Visual Studio - multiple versions :) .. I almost struggled a week to identify the root cause - In my case, I have two accounts - parent company and Client account. I installed VS 2019 for my company azure, VS 2022 for client sake to differentiate the code bases. In code along with azure credentials, supplied chain credentials as VisualStudio, also VSCode creds too..
Even if I signIn as Client in both VS2019 and VS2022, VS2019 being reverting back to company's account.. strange!!

so, I had to Uninstall quirky VS2019, and signIn VS2022 for client, the issue resolved...
Please make sure one version of VStudio only exists, if the error keep coming in..! Hope it Helps, HydTechie

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was defaulting to named pipes or something but when I changed the server name to the TCP format, like

```
tcp:server-name-xxxxxxx.database.windows.net, 1433
```

It was able to connect. Then I could just connect to `server-name-xxxxxxx.database.windows.net` and it worked like normal, as if it started to prefer TCP connections.

It was weird because creating a new query window through the Object Explorer pane worked but using the Change Connection button failed, so I knew permissions and the server were fine and it was my new install of SSMS v19 that was acting weird.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue when connecting to a sql-managed-instance. Where when I connected (on another environment) to a database with the same name, but running on a sql-2022 vm, it succeeded. When I removed some SPACES in the connectionstring, it worked also for the sql-managed instance.

`$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = {0} ; Initial Catalog = {1} ;TrustServerCertificate=True;" -f $dbServerName, $dbName`

changed into:

`$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog={1};TrustServerCertificate=True;" -f $dbServerName, $dbName`

Hope this helps someone. Key were the spaces surrounding the db-name, but removed the others as well to be consequent.

Answer (score 0):

Other Azure-related permissions to also check that helped resolve this for me:

- Ensure you are in any [Entra groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/how-to-manage-groups) that have access to the database to which you are trying to connect
- Ensure that if [Entra PIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/id-governance/privileged-identity-management/pim-configure) is in use, you have extended your lease
- As above, make sure you are connecting to a named database rather than [`master`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database)